# number goes second time less then 100

Tags: java, android, variables, android-sensors

i am using the orientation sensor in the android app. I want to find out when the sensor value goes less than 100 second time. how to find it.

```
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
             {
              value= (event.values[0]);


     if (value<100){

        }
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep of track of it in a class variable. I'm assuming that you just want to detect it going under 100 twice at any time, not twice consecutively.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    {
         value= (event.values[0]);


        if (value<100){
           if (!lessThanBefore) //first time it is less than 100, mark 
           {
               lessThanBefore= true;
           }
           else
           {
                //CONDITION DETECTED...
           }
        }

      }}
```

Comment: i want to detect when the sensor value goes below 100 second time then play a sound. for example when the sensor value first time 0 to 100 no sound after this when it goes again below 100 then sound is played.

Comment: @vik You play the sound where is says `//CONDITION DETECTED`

Comment: its not working, i check this the sound is played when the value goes less then 100 first time. i want the sound is not played first time otherwise its played

Comment: Is the sound playing at all?

Comment: sound is playing every time value goes less then 100. first time also playing.

Comment: `lessThanBefore` should be initialized as false. Are you doing that?

Comment: Can you use add System.out.println("Test")  right below the `value = (event.values[0])` to see how many times that is entered on one time below 100?`

Comment: i try this
  if (!lessThanBefore) //first time it is less than 100, mark 
              {
                  lessThanBefore= true;
                  System.out.println("Test");
              }
its never be called

Comment: Are you sure `lessThanBefore` is not initialized to true somewhere else in the code?

Comment: yes. sure its not just initialised once: private boolean lessThanBefore= false;

Comment: Hmm. Seems like there must be something else going on then.